# bind к загруженным элементам

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код:

```
$("ul#mmenu li").hover(
    function(){$("span.move, span.onoff",this).css("opacity",1)},
    function(){$("span.move, span.onoff",this).css("opacity",0)}
);
```

Аяксом грузится контент, включающий в себя вышеуказанные элементы. Как `"прибиндить"` к ним этот hover?

Comment: Попробуйте в аяксе возвращать этот же скрипт.

Comment: Или, как вариант, `$(function(){$("AJAX_RETURNER").find("ul#mmenu li")});`

Comment: Не работает. Да и мне кажется, что это не выход. Надо как-то через bind или live, просто я не могу никак разобраться.

Comment: ПОпробуйте не HTML возвращать, а JSON с указателем на функцию, которая будет выстраивать этот HTML. ТОгда вопросов не возникнет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function AA(){$("span.move, span.onoff",this).css("opacity",1)}
function BB(){$("span.move, span.onoff",this).css("opacity",0)}
$("ul#mmenu li").hover(AA, BB);

$.load(_blablabla_);
_blablabla_.hover(AA, BB);
```

Хотя лучше всего это повесить через live:

```
$("ul#mmenu li").live('mouseenter', AA).live('mouseleave', BB);
```

Comment: Нагуглил, сделал 2-м способом, потом прочитал ваш ответ )) Но все равно спасибо!